# spark 1.6 task never ends

Tags: apache-spark, task

I have a spark job that run and never ends. 
The job retrieve data from an hdfs

I have a 6 nodes with 94Go memory and 16 core each
The job almost completes but freezes at the 2 last tasks on a node.

I monitored with jvisualvm the processes for each node and the driver, and i don't have any issues of memory or CPU , regarding what i can see in jvisualvm.

In the spark ui when i see logs for each node ans the driver, there is no errors.

I think that this is an issue with data size because the issue occurs only when (3) + (4) + (5) + (6) are actives (not commented)

```
      .select($"time", $"name" , $"classes") // (2)
      .withColumn("classe", explode($"classes"))   // (3)
      .drop($"classes") // (4)
      .withColumn("test", $"classes.test") // (5)
      .filter(($"test" === "a simple test ") // (6)
      .groupBy($"name") // (7)
```

Any idea of how i can find the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the input dataframe's schema, some records from dataframe and output dataframe that you are expecting. By the way, i don't see any aggregation functions after grouping the dataframe which actually makes it a `org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset`(not a dataframe)

Comment: Upgrade to Spark 2.4.*? :) (:

Comment: I think  where is the issue, but i can't manage to solve it. in The spark ui i can see that i have 200 partitions  198 SUCCESS with : 375.0 KB / 0  (375.0 KB / 0) and 2 with : 431.6 MB / 2580364. This means that all data are being processed by only 2 tasks ans data is not correctly partitioned. but none of my manual repartition worked ... using repartition function